# Web Audio API and streaming audio

Tags: javascript, streaming, web-audio-api

I want create live audio streaming by websockets.

- This what works for me is listening microphone, create PCM, load PCM to BufferSource and playback.
- This what doesn't work is send PCM by websockets or other protocol.

I get microphone permission by:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, initializeRecorder, errorCallback);
```

Then record microphone and create PCM:

```
function initializeRecorder(MediaStream) {
    var sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(MediaStream);

    var recorder = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 2, 2);
    recorder.onaudioprocess = recorderProcess;

    sourceNode.connect(recorder);
    recorder.connect(audioCtx.destination);
}
```

Later I push every PCM to BufferSource and playback:

```
function recorderProcess(e) {
    var buff = e.inputBuffer;

    var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buff;
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.start();
}
```

It works well.

But if I want send **var buff** to server, I get [image] for every PCM.

This PCM is Float32Array type and I don't understand why I can't send it like it is.

I can convert this to UInt16 by script:

```
function convertFloat32ToInt16(buffer) {
    var l = buffer.length;
    var buf = new Int16Array(l);
    while(l--) {
        buf[l] = Math.min(1, buffer[l]) * 0x7FFF;
    }
    return buf.buffer;
}
```

But I don't know how to decode this later for Float32Array back to push to BufferSource on another client.

Comment: Are you using any websocket library for sending/receiving the data? What are you running on the server (and what does the code look like where you receive the data)?

Answer (score 0):

You can I think, 
whats the problem if you try:

```
var mybuffer = new Float32Array(pcmDataFromSocket);
```